# How to register a component for testing with ember-qunit?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-qunit

I'm trying to use ember-qunit for testing.
I have this pseudo-code here: (http://jsbin.com/zejacati/5/edit)

```js
Ember.Foo = Ember.Namespace.create();

Ember.Foo.FooComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  template: Ember.Handlebars.compile('<h2>Hello!</h2>')
});

Ember.Handlebars.helper('foo-component', Ember.Foo.FooComponent);

window.App = Ember.Application.create();

window.App.setupForTesting();
emq.globalize();
setResolver(Ember.DefaultResolver.create({
  namespace: window.App
}));

moduleForComponent('foo-component', 'Foo component testing');

test('First true test', function () {
  var component = this.subject();
  ok(true, true);
});
```

and ember sayed me:

> Setup failed on First true test: Attempting to register an unknown factory: `component:foo-component`

I think the problem in resolver, but I don't know how fix it.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem might be because you put `FooComponent` on the `Ember` object instead of the `App` object.

Instead of:

```
Ember.Foo.FooComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  template: Ember.Handlebars.compile('<h2>Hello!</h2>')
});
```

try this instead:

```
App.FooComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  template: Ember.Handlebars.compile('<h2>Hello!</h2>')
});
```

... because that is where Ember's default resolver would look for `component:foo-component`.

I am not familiar with `Ember.Namespace` (have not used it before), and thus also how it would impact this test - so try this version first, without any namespace, and then try to work the namespace back in.